# Unable to perform actions after login in codeception due to authentication failure [Not able to send tokens]

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I'm working on automating testing using codeception. How do I perform action after login.

For better understanding I have posted my code below.

```
    $I->amOnRoute('login');;
    $I->sendPOST('/login', ['email' => 'un', 'password' => `enter 
    code here`'pwd']);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
```

Above lines of code works fine, but I get 401 authentication error when I continue with below code

```
        $I->sendAjaxPostRequest('/adminproxy/create-entity',[ 
         "name" => 123123123123,
        "title" =>  123123123,
        "realm_id" =>  1,
        "description" =>  123123123123,
        "status" =>  'ACTIVE',
        "entity_type" => 'Workspace' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem that you mix actions of Laravel5 module and REST module.
Instead of using `sendPOST`, it could be better to [submit a form](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#submitForm).

```
$I->amOnRoute('login');
$I->submitForm('#login-form', ['email' => 'un', 'password' => 'pwd']);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
```